# Contour and Perspective Plots for rsm object for each level of a factor

Tags: r, plot, statistics, contour

I want to get Contour and Perspective Plots for `rsm` object for each level of a factor here for `Block`.

### Output

[image]

[image]

### Minimum working example

```
library(rsm)
CR <- coded.data (ChemReact, x1~(Time-85)/5, x2~(Temp-175)/5)
CR.rs2 <- rsm (Yield ~ Block + SO(x1,x2), data=CR)
summary(CR.rs2)
persp(
    CR.rs2
  , x1 ~ x2
  , col = rainbow(50)
  , ticktype = "simple"
  , contour = ("colors")
  )

contour(CR.rs2, ~ x1 + x2, image = TRUE,  at = summary(CR.rs2)$canonical$xs)
```

### Edited

Desired output

**Contour Plots**

1. Contour plot between Time and Temp for Block 1
2. Contour plot between Time and Temp for Block 2

**Perspective Plots**

1. Perspective plot between Time and Temp for Block 1
2. Perspective plot between Time and Temp for Block 2

Comment: Should we assume that ChemReact is an included dataset in rsm? From context  It appears that there is a persp-method defined for rsm-objects.

Comment: So to clarify:  You want scales that show the predicted level for each Block?

Comment: I need two contours and two perspective plots for each level of block as there are two levels of block factor.

Comment: Are you proposing to overlay the "two contours" (which would seem to be impossible) or are they going to be separate plots. (PLEASE explain fully what you are expecting.)

Comment: Sorry @BondedDust for any confusion. I need separate contour and perspective plots for each level of block. For the data at hand there would be two contour and two perspective plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the block in the `at` argument:

```
contour(CR.rs2, ~ x1 + x2, image = TRUE,  
    at = c(summary(CR.rs2)$canonical$xs, Block="B1"))

contour(CR.rs2, ~ x1 + x2, image = TRUE,  
    at = c(summary(CR.rs2)$canonical$xs, Block="B2"))
```

... and same with `persp`

Comment: Thanks @Prof. Russ Lenth for your help. This is what I was looking for. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The line in persp.lm that sets up the data for the persp part is:

```
plot.data = contour.lm(x, form, at, bounds, zlim, xlabs, 
    atpos = atpos, plot.it = FALSE)
```

Looking at plot.data's construction in contour.lm yous ee it is a list:

```
 plot.data[[i]] = list(x = x, y = y, z = matrix(z, nrow = length(x)), 
        labs = labs)
```

Comparing the output from contour.lm and the coefficients in the origianl model you can see that what gets plotted (with a max of 82) is a mean response surface (since the Intercept is 84.095 and the Block effect is -4.458. So take the output form contour.lm and use it to plot estiamtes that are adjusted appropriately to be the individual effects:

```
> plt <- contour.lm(CR.rs2, x1 ~ x2, plot.it=FALSE)
> names(plt)
[1] "x2 ~ x1"
> str(plt)
List of 1
 $ x2 ~ x1:List of 5
  ..$ x   : num [1:26] 168 168 169 170 170 ...
  ..$ y   : num [1:26] 77.9 78.5 79.1 79.6 80.2 ...
  ..$ z   : num [1:26, 1:26] 75.5 75.8 76.1 76.4 76.7 ...
  ..$ labs: Named chr [1:5] "Temp" "Time" "x2" "x1" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "x2" "x1" "x" "y" ...
  ..$ zlim: num [1:2] 75.5 82.1
```

Comment: Please have a look on the answer of Prof. Russ Lenth.